# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while executing a shell script

Tags: python, linux

Am trying to execute a shell script from a python script but i end up with OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when opening shell script.

python script permission -> -rwxr-xr-x

shell script permission -> -rwxr-xr-x

Permissions looks good to me. Not able to understand why am ending up with below error.

Code Part:

```
RC = subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/control.sh", "My Servlet", "stop"])
trace("Return Code %s " %RC)
if not RC == 0:
   trace('Command: %s, Failed to stop.' % cmd)
   f.close()
   sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Can you add the code part, where you are executing shell script?

Comment: How is the python script being called?

Comment: Code Part - python script. ```RC = subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/control.sh", "My Servlet", "stop"])
trace("Return Code %s " %RC)
if not RC == 0:
   trace('Command: %s, Failed to stop.' % cmd)
   f.close()
   sys.exit(1)